# How to remove openvpn profile from windows 10

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to delete the outdated profiles of open vpn from the GUI in Windows 10. There does not seem to be a delete option. Any pointers on how to get rid of old profiles would be helpful. The user manual says to use the delete button but there does not seem to be a delete button. I have  also tried to run this as administrator. Open VPN version 11.14.0.0.

[open vpn gui windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0cmh.png)

Answer (score 10):

i needed a rubber ducky ... I tried the "edit config" of the profile and then pressed save as.

The save as address is %USERPROFILE%\OpenVPN\config\ with subsequent folders that contain the profiles. just delete the offending folders and they get removed from the GUI after application restart.

Comment: I just needed the path `%USERPROFLE%` and I was able to find what I needed. thanks.

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez correction WINDOWS+R then type %USERPROFILE% ok

Comment: brilliant, did the same on my various profiles to track their locations

Comment: Adding/Removing config files from `C:\Users%USERNAME%\OpenVPN\config` didn't fix the problem for me. Instead adding/removing them in `C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config` fixed it.

Comment: "application restart" - thank you.

Answer (score 8):

OpenVPN GUI will save configuration files in following address:

> C:\Users%USERNAME%\OpenVPN\config

in order to remove profiles you can delete folders in above directory

Also [as SomeGuy pointed out in the openvpn-forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=23127#p66756) another place for configuration files could be

> C:/Program Files/OpenVPN/config
> C:/Program Files (x86)/OpenVPN/config

Answer (score 1):

My "OpenVPN Connect" client (version 3.3.1 (2222))  stores the profiles in directory:

> %APPDATA%\OpenVPN Connect\profiles

Delete the corresponding file.

NOTE: "OpenVPN Connect" client on Windows 10 does have a delete profile option.
Go to tab "Profiles", click on the pencil and click on button "delete profile"